# Predicate logic proof, can't get to the right solution

Tags: predicate-logic

So I have tried to make a solution for a predicate logic proof, and would like if someone could give a hint to come to the correct proof.

I already know that Line 11 is incorrect since it only holds in the assumption. 
And the same for line 9, since its in two different assumptions.

Any help to how I should proceed, would help me a lot

[image: Picture of my solution]